# How can I use restsharp by calling get method?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, restful-architecture

My question is simple. I want to learn restsharp because of that. I used fake restful service "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" but queryResult is null what is wrong with it? how can ı get json data from "**https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts**" by using restsharp?

```js
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1.RestfulWebServ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var client = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
            var request = new RestRequest("posts/", Method.GET);
            var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Person>>(request).Data;

        }
    }

    internal class Person
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I just copy-paste your code and run - I get expected result (100 person entries, not null).

Comment: Yes (like Evk wrote) now I tried it too. It works.

Comment: Thanks guys; I guess my company security shitt. Thanks again